# Как лучше заменить елемент в блоке при клике с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть 4 кнопочки, при клике на которые будет меняться содержимое (которого довольно много, врятли стоит прописывать через .html. Знаю что можно через .show() и .hide() такое сделать, но получается многовато кода, как лучше всего такое несложное задание реализовать?

Comment: Слишком обще. Подробности и код в студию.

Comment: можно использовать принцип вкладок: каждой кнопке свой дата-таргет. кода много не будет. примеры можно в бутстрапе подсмотреть или где-угодно-ещё

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#buttons a').click(function () {
  var index = $(this).index();
  
  $('#buttons a.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  
  $('#content div.showed').removeClass('showed');
  $('#content div').eq(index).addClass('showed');
});
```

```css
#buttons a {
  color: #111;
  display: block;
  float:left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  
  transition: .15s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: .15s ease-out;
}

#buttons a:hover,
#buttons a.active {
  background: darkblue;  
  border-color: darkblue;  
  color: #fff;
}

#content {
  clear: both;
  background: #efefef;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
}

#content div {
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  
  transition: .15s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: .15s ease-out;
}

#content div.showed {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="buttons">
  <a href="#" class="active">Кнопка 1</a>
  <a href="#">Кнопка 2</a>
  <a href="#">Кнопка 3</a>
  <a href="#">Кнопка 4</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div class="showed">Контент 1</div>
  <div>Контент 2</div>
  <div>Контент 3</div>
  <div>Контент 4</div>
</div>
```